# Graphics2D.setComposite Null pointer exception

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel, paint

I'm having a null pointer exception when setting an alphacomposite.
This is my code for my panel:

```
package org.speedygoverment;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Composite;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ImageIcon menulogoimage = new ImageIcon(
            Game.class.getResource("/res/logo.png"));
    public int menulogoy = 0 - (menulogoimage.getIconHeight() * 2);
    private Game game;
    public int startbtnx = -100;
    public int startbtny = getHeight() / 2 - 36;

    public Panel(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public AlphaComposite createComposite(float f1, float f2) {
        float percentage = (f1 * 100f) / f2;
        return AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,
                percentage / 100f);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics gg) {
        super.paint(gg);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gg;
        if (game.state == State.MENU) {
            Image img = new ImageIcon(Game.class.getResource("/res/city.png"))
                    .getImage();
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            g.drawImage(menulogoimage.getImage(), 32, menulogoy, null);
            g.setFont(new Font(game.font.getFontName(), Font.PLAIN, getWidth() / 128));
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString(
                    "Made by BadBoy6767, lvivtotoro, Midnightas, Darkastronaut",
                    32, getHeight() - 48);
        } else if (game.state == State.GAME) {
            Composite original = g.getComposite();
            Image imgoff = new ImageIcon(
                    Game.class.getResource("/res/city_off.png")).getImage();
            Image img = new ImageIcon(Game.class.getResource("/res/city.png"))
                    .getImage();
            g.drawImage(imgoff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            g.setComposite(createComposite(game.powerhandler.power, 100));
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            g.setComposite(original);
        }
    }

}
```

The null pointer exception is at line 55:

```
g.setComposite(createComposite(game.powerhandler.power, 100));
```

I do not know where the null pointer is exactly happening, it only says its on line 55 and then a bunch of java classes. This is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.speedygoverment.Panel.paint(Panel.java:55)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I do not think that I need to show **all** of my classes, this is the only one I have problems with.
Also I'm trying to make a transparent image using AlphaComposite, but thats the thing that doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The exception is clear in `org.speedygoverment.Panel` class at line 55 there is a null pointer reference. I suspect `game.powerhandler` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Would you check whether game.powerhandler is null?